# collapsing a variable number of elements that contain child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, vue.js

I have a web app that displays short stories, and gives a text summary for each chapter of that short story.

The elements that contains the story is sortable within the parent div of class "stories". 
Additionally, the elements that contain the chapter summaries are also sortable within the parent div of class "chapters".

This sorting is done using a jQuery plug-in.

However, I would like to add a react, vue, or even jQuery plugin that allows the parent element of each book to be collaspable.

I did try jQuery accordian, but that only allows one element to be open at any given time.

I then tried a react library called react-sortable-hoc, found here: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc

However, when implemented, broke the sorting ability of my stories and chapter summaries.

So I was wondering if anyone could reccomend a library/component that can collapse a dynamic number of elements that contain child elements.

Here is an example of what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="stories sortable">

    <div class="storySummary"> 
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header shortStoryTitle collapsable">To Build a Fire</div>    <!-- desired functionality: collapse when clicked -->
            <div>
                <div class="chapters sortable">
                    <div class="chapterSummary">
                        Chapter Summary Text for Chapter #1
                    </div>
                    <div class="chapterSummary">
                        Chapter Summary Text for Chapter #2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="storySummary">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header shortStoryTitle collapsable">An Occurrence at Owl Creek Bridge</div> <!-- desired functionality: collapse when clicked -->
            <div>
                <div class="chapters sortable">
                    <div class="chapterSummary">
                        Chapter Summary Text for Chapter #1
                    </div>
                    <div class="chapterSummary">
                        Chapter Summary Text for Chapter #2
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="storySummary">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header shortStoryTitle collapsable">A Horseman in the Sky</div> <!-- desired functionality: collapse when clicked -->
            <div>
                <div class="chapters sortable">
                    <div class="chapterSummary">
                        Chapter Summary Text for Chapter #1
                    </div>
                    <div class="chapterSummary">
                        Chapter Summary Text for Chapter #2
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I just used a Bootstrap collapse/expand feature to accomplish something similar. Pretty simple to use

Comment: @BSchnitzel Can you please let me know a link or resource to this feature?  Thanks!